# JPA creating a CriteriaQuery for a JOIN statement with attributes in an embedded primary key

Tags: java, jpa, join

I'm having some trouble creating a TypedQuery for a JOIN statement using JPA, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

As an example, suppose I have a table, Person, with a composite primary key (PERSONID, FISRTNAME, LASTNAME):

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
PERSONID int NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
LASTNAME varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
AGE int,
CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON PRIMARY KEY (PERSONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
);
```

I can then use JPA to generate an entity class with it's composite primary key, which would look something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private PersonPK id;
    private int age;
    //constructor and getters and setters...
}

@Embeddable
public class PersonPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int personid;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    //constructor and getters and setters...
}
```

Let's suppose also I have another table, Order, also with a composite primary key (PERSONID, FIRSTNAME; LASTNAME, PRODUCTID):

```
CREATE TABLE Order (
PERSONID int NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
LASTNAME varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
PRODUCTID int NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION varchar2(255),
CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER PRIMARY KEY (PERSONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PRODUCTID)
);
```

And JPA would generate some similar looking entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private OrderPK id;
    private String description;
    //constructor and getters and setters...
}

@Embeddable
public class OrderPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int personid;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int productid
    //constructor and getters and setters...
}
```

Okay, so probably not the most sensible schema but it works for my example. So, this is the SQL statement I'd like to reproduce:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person
INNER JOIN Order
ON Person.PERSONID = Order.PERSONID
AND Person.FIRSTNAME = Order.FIRSTNAME
AND Person.LASTNAME = Order.LASTNAME;
```

So probably not in this schema but for my project in Oracle SQL it produces the results I want. So, here's my question, how do I create this query using a JPA?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistance.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceunitname");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> person = query.from(Person.class);
Join<Person, Order> orders = person.join("personid"); //the problem is with this line, explained in more detail below
query.multiselect(orders); // not sure if this is correct
TypedQuery<Person> q = em.createQuery(query); // not sure if this is correct
List<Person> results = q.getResultList(); // not sure if this is correct
```

The problem I have found after following some online tutorials, is with the line:

`Join<Person, Order> orders = person.join("personid");`

because the attribute personid is inside the embeddable class PersonPK, and not in Person, due to it being a composite primary key.

Obviously, supposing "personid" correctly identifies the attribute in the primary key, this would only create a join statement on personid, and not on the firstname nor the lastname.

So, my question is, how can I correctly create a TypedQuery statement that will create the JOIN statement as specified above?

Comment: why use an `@Embeddable` if you can just annotate multiple attributes with `@Id` to create an composite key?

Comment: it wasn't something I had specifically chosen since I generated all of my entities using the JPA generate entities tool. is there no way to do it if the composite primary key is in a separate @embeddable class, then?

Comment: you should be able to access it with `person.join("id.personid")`. that tells JPA that the field you want to access is not a field of the class itself, but from the field of the class ("id" specifies the field in Person class and "personid" specifies the filed in the key class)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have tried this and it didn't work.
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [id.person] is not present in the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@995482901:Person`

Comment: its not `id.person`. it is `id.personid`

Comment: Sorry this was a typo from copying the code from my actual project. I tried: "variable name in entity class"."variable name in embeddable class" and it didn't work.

Comment: next shot: `person.join("id").<Integer>get("personid")`

Comment: For further information you might want to look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: Also doesn't work, the join() method requires a String as a parameter which is the name of the attribute, and returns the resulting Join<X,Y>, adding a get here would return the corresponding path<Y> to the attribute, and does not compile. Also, you cannot cast a class inline as you specified, it again will not compile.

Comment: i think your whole model is a bit off. from how i see it, your `Person` class should have a list of orders, while each order should have a person which it is associated with. this way you doN't need to create the join yourself

Comment: I appreciate the help, but as I stated this was just a simple example I created to illustrate my problem. I'd like to know how to create the specified JOIN statement, as done in SQL, not ways around the problem.

Comment: the problem is, that your classes do not exactly reflect the tables. move the fields out of the embedded key and you can easily do the JOIN "just like in SQL"

Comment: The classes do exactly reflect the tables and they are generated from them by JPA. I find it hard to believe that there is no way of accessing the variables inside of an @Embeddable class.
I have achieved something similar in a SELECT statement as follows:
`query.select(person).where(cb.equal(person.get("id").get("personid"), "myPersonId");`
Surely there is something similar for the join() method...

Answer (score 0):

The join() method is also used to navigate to embedded attributes:

```
Join<Person, Order> orders = person.join("id").join("personid")
```

Source:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-from-join